# Relationship between Cartan sub algebra and Casimir operators?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to understand some of the definitions in Lie algebra/Lie groups.

So far I believe;

- A Cartan subalgebra is the largest possible set of elements that commute with each other in some representation. This would be made up of elements from the group.
- The generators of the group form the algebra of the group.
- Any operator that commutes with all the generators is described as a Casimir operator. The Casimir operators depend on the representation.

(Are any of these points wrong?)

I am wondering if there is some relationship between the Cartan sub algebra and the Casimir operators.

Comment: For Cartan subalgebra see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_subalgebra). It seems you are assuming that the Lie algebra is semisimple?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I wasn't aware that I was assuming it to be semi-simple. Is this because if it were not semi-simple there would be abelian invariant sub-algebras, and a Cartan subalgebra must be abelian but not invariant, and you cannot have both in the same group? (why can't you have both in the same group?)

Comment: If the Lie algebra is not semisimple, the Cartan subalgebra is nilpotent, but need not be abelian, see the link. And we are in Lie algebras, not groups.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Surely _reductive_ is good enough instead of semisimple (I like my general linear groups).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, definitely, I agree. Experience, though, with "Casimir or Cartan questions" have shown that often semisimple is implicitly assumed.